# NoMethodError: undefined method `admin=' for #<User:0x00000002ceae30>

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin, rails-console

> Currently I'm using the latest version of rails_admin and devise gem and have to two signed_in users

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 4912
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
2.3.1 :001 > u = User.first
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, email: "dhami.khawas@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-08-15 10:26:16", updated_at: "2016-08-16 12:48:11"> 
2.3.1 :002 > u = User.last
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 2, email: "linux@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-08-16 10:03:10", updated_at: "2016-08-19 08:18:23">
```

2.3.1 :003

> How do I make any one of them as Admin User? I tried running below operation but ended up in errors.

```
2.3.1 :004 > u.admin
NoMethodError: undefined method `admin' for #<User:0x00000002d3dbf8>
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
from (irb):4
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
from /home/bikal/workspace/concert_nepal/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/bikal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
2.3.1 :005 >
```

Comment: You need to add field admin in migration. Devise doesn't add it.

Comment: rails generate migration AddAdminToUsers Admin:boolean. Is this ok @MikhailMalov? I'm new to ROR, will you please guide me little further if I didn't get u...Thanks in advance.

Comment: After rails generated that migration, did you run `rake db:migrate` and then restart your console?

Comment: @TamerShlash, I have added migration running AddAdminToUsers Admin:boolean, and got errors in rails console as, 2.3.1 :004 > u.admin
NoMethodError: undefined method `admin' for #<User:0x00000002e08740>
Did you mean?  Admin
               Admin=
               Admin?
 from /home/bikal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'

Comment: try `u.Admin` because you add `Admin:boolean`

Comment: Thanks @MikhailMalov, really appreciate your help. It worked.